# Curve defined via integral

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $z:I\longrightarrow\mathbb{S}^2$ be a birregular curve parametrized by arc length. Let $x:J\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be a curve given by $x(t)=\int_{0}^{t} z(\tau)d\tau$. Compute the curvature and torsion.

First of all, by fundamental theorem of calculus $||x'(t)||=||z(t)||=1$. Therefore, $x(t)$ is regular and parametrized by arc length. If we compute the curvature: $\kappa_x=||t'_x||=||z'(t)||=1$ (A little bit explained $t_x=\frac{x'(t)}{||x'(t)||}=x'(t)\Longrightarrow t'_x=x''(t)=z'(t))$.

Thus, $x(t)$ is birregular.

For torsion, we have to compute $\tau_x=<n'_x,b_x>$.
The normal vector is:
\begin{equation}\label{nor}
n_x=\frac{t'_x}{||t'_x||}={\frac{z'(t)}{\underbrace{||z'(t)||}_{=1}}}=z'(t).
\end{equation}
And the binormal vector is:
\begin{equation}\label{bin}
b_x=t_x\times n_x=z(t)\times z'(t),
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\tau_x & =<n'_x,b_x>=<z''(t),z(t)\times z'(t)>=\\
& =<\lambda n_z,(\alpha t_z+\beta n_z+\eta b_z)\times \mu t_z>=\\
& =<\lambda n_z,\alpha t_z\times \mu t_z+\beta n_z\times \mu t_z+\eta b_z\times \mu t_z>=\\
& =<\lambda n_z, 0-\mu\beta b_z+\eta\mu n_z>=\\
& =<\lambda n_z, \nu b_z+\rho n_z>=\\
& =<\lambda n_z, \nu b_z>+<\lambda n_z, \rho n_z>=\\
& =0+\xi ||n_z||^2=\xi ||n_z||^2.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

As $z(t)$ is arc length I know that i can write $z$ as a combination of $(t_z,n_z,b_z)$ but I write arbitrary coefficients. I would like to know what the coefficients are. Maybe as $z$ is arc length the coefficients are 1?

Comment: Go back to your first line for torsion. Note that $'$ is orthogonal to both $$ and $''$, so the torsion will be (up to sign) $\|z\times z''\| = \|z''\|\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors.

Comment: @TedShifrin  I understand that $z\times z'$ is gonna be parallel to $z''$ that's ok. I don't know why are you taking $z$ and $z''$ in  $||z\times z''||=||z''||sin\theta$. I'd have $\tau _x=<z'', z\times z'>=||z''||^2*(some constant)$

Comment: Remember that $\langle z'',z\times z'\rangle = \langle z',z''\times z\rangle$.

Comment: Oh, and why do you say $z\times z’$ will be parallel to $z”$? That's wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin If $z\times z'$ is orthogonal to $z''$, we'd have that $z,z',z''$ are coplanar. That could happen if the curve is not flat?

Comment: I think I've never use that property, $<z'', z\times z'>=<z', z''\times z>.  (Is like adjoint operators?)

Comment: As $z'$ and $z''$ are orthogonal, we have only two options: 1- $z\times z'$ orthogonal to $z''$ 2- $z\times z'$ parallel to $z''$

Comment: First, that property comes most directly from the properties of determinants, although one can interpret it geometrically in terms of volume of a parallelepiped. Second, you seem stuck in a rut of thinking two vectors are either parallel or orthogonal. The one correct statement is the one I made, namely that since $z$ and $z''$ are both orthogonal to $z'$, $z\times z''$ must be a scalar multiple of $z'$. We actually don't know much about $z\times z'$ and $z''$ other than by using my symmetry formula.

Comment: Thanks, I will think about it. Yeah i'm a little bit stuck in that haha. Thank you anyway.